# Used "import os" seen as unused

Tags: python, pycharm

In the midst of a mid-sized PyCharm project, I have a number of imports of built-in libraries that are used in the code, but are not seen by PyCharm as used.   An example is the one below.   "os" is used four lines after the import, but the import is still labeled as by PyCharm as unused.

What gives?

[image: Pycharm unused import]

---

Edit:
If I remove the "import os" statement, then I get the following error when loading the module in an interpreter.

```
  File "texts.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings"
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe you've already imported `os` previously?

Comment: File a ticket at JetBrains.

Comment: @goncalopp - nope.  "import os" is the first line in the file.

Comment: What version of PyCharm are you using?  I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1 and it works fine.

Comment: PyCharm Professional Edition 3.4.1

Comment: Have you tried to reset the Python Inspections in Settings? (uncheck -> Apply -> close PyCharm -> open PyCharm -> check and Apply) With version 3.4.0 my Python Inspections became crazy, I did this and fixed the problem.  And you could temporary disble Django Inspections.

Comment: @Trimax unchecked, closed, restarted, and checked Python in inspection settings.  No change in behavior.

Comment: Bad Luck :-( Then, as @Tichodroma said: Ticket at JetBrains support.

Comment: And if you remove that 'unused' import you actually get an error? This was not clear from the question.

Comment: @tobias_k Yup, I get an error. Edited.

Comment: @tobias_k with "import os" removed from the code, PyCharm doesn't show any errors.  It says "all okay"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this problem in [PY-11472](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11472).